# Is the Google Drive web host link feature in danger of being phased out?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, google-drive-api

I am working on an Android app that stores log on a client's Google Drive. We push static HTML/Javascript files to said Drive in order for the user to be able to read their logs in an user friendly way via their browser. This feature worked relatively well until now (notwithstanding some glitches due to server updates in the last few months).

2 weeks ago (.e. from the beginning of October 2014) we saw that the newer user interface of Google Drive has dropped the web host link capability altogether. For legacy accounts this feature is still there, but not for newer created accounts from the aforementioned date.

Does that mean that Google is planning to ultimately drop this feature, or is it going to be available for the foreseeable future, even if only accessible programmatically via SDK?

Note that we tested to see if programmatic access is affected, and it seems to work fine. We used java SDK function getWebViewLink() (class File) in order to get the link programmatically, and it still works no 1 for now. But the change in UI from Google does worry us that this feature will be dropped, like Dropbox dropped theirs recently. Is that the case? If so, what is the expected timeline of feature deprecation and eventual disappearance?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they moved/changed it but didn't remove it altogether. The instructions from Google on [how to host webpages with Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) worked for me using an account I created after the UI change (after you posted this question).

Since their [latest blog post on deprecating APIs](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html) does not say anything about getting rid of the web host feature, you are probably fine.

*If so, what is the expected timeline of feature deprecation and eventual disappearance?*

If the APIs they're deprecating are anything to go by, even if they do get rid of web hosting it will be a couple of years between the time they announce it and it actually being unavailable. It's not a perfect comparison since those are entire APIs and this is just a feature but it doesn't seem like they make a habit of making something unavailable at the drop of a hat.